# Speed up ActiveRecord query within an each block

Tags: ruby, activerecord, refactoring

I have the following API endpoint that builds an array of `DateTime` objects and then iterates through it. For each date, the code finds the posts that were updated that day and plucks the `completed_requests_count`. It then sums those up and pushes that data into a `data` object to be further processed and returned to the client. This whole process is fairly slow. Right now it takes an average of 400ms just for the `ActiveRecord` portion of this code to execute.

What I would like to know is how I can further optimize this to cut that time in half (or better). The bottleneck seems to be within the two `each` blocks. Is there some way to iterate through the dates and pluck the values I need without performing an individual query for each iteration?

```
def dashboard_metrics
    # Get all TwitterPosts, FacebookPosts, LinkedInPosts, and InstagramPosts
    tw_posts = current_user.twitter_posts
    fb_posts = current_user.facebook_posts
    li_posts = current_user.linked_in_posts
    ig_posts = current_user.instagram_posts

    # Build date range if custom dates selected
    if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
        @start_date = DateTime.parse(params[:start_date]).midnight
        @end_date = DateTime.parse(params[:end_date]).midnight

        # Build array of DateTime objects
        dates = (@start_date..@end_date).to_a
        num_days = dates.count
        dates_for_last_period = ((@end_date - (2 * num_days).days)..(@start_date - 1.day)).to_a
    else
        # Number of days for window
        num_days = params[:num_days].present? && params[:num_days].to_i > 0 ? params[:num_days].to_i : 30

        # Build array of DateTime objects
        dates = (0..num_days).map { |n| (DateTime.now - n.days).midnight }.reverse
        dates_for_last_period = ((num_days + 1)..(num_days * 2)).map { |n| (DateTime.now - n.days).midnight }.reverse
    end

    # Initialize data object
    data = [{ key: 'Twitter', values: [] }, { key: 'Facebook', values: [] }, { key: 'LinkedIn', values: [] }, { key: 'Instagram', values: [] }]

    # Initialize Reach and Value counts
    reach_this_period = 0
    reach_last_period = 0

    # Iterate over array of DateTime objects and increment/push values for each date to data object
    dates.each do |date|
        # Get Amplify counts for each post type and multiply by average follower/friend count for platform
        tw_amplify_count = (tw_posts.where("twitter_posts.updated_at >= ? and twitter_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 300
        fb_amplify_count = (fb_posts.where("facebook_posts.updated_at >= ? and facebook_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 350
        li_amplify_count = (li_posts.where("linked_in_posts.updated_at >= ? and linked_in_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 700
        ig_amplify_count = (ig_posts.where("instagram_posts.updated_at >= ? and instagram_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 200

        # Push [date, amplify_count] pairs to data object for each post type
        data[0][:values] << [date, tw_amplify_count]
        data[1][:values] << [date, fb_amplify_count]
        data[2][:values] << [date, li_amplify_count]
        data[3][:values] << [date, ig_amplify_count]

        reach_this_period += tw_amplify_count + fb_amplify_count + li_amplify_count + ig_amplify_count
    end

    # Iterate over array of DateTime objects for previous N days and get sign_in and confirmation counts
    dates_for_last_period.each do |date|
        # Get Amplify counts for each post type and multiply by average follower/friend count for platform
        tw_amplify_count = (tw_posts.where("twitter_posts.updated_at >= ? and twitter_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 208
        fb_amplify_count = (fb_posts.where("facebook_posts.updated_at >= ? and facebook_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 200
        li_amplify_count = (li_posts.where("linked_in_posts.updated_at >= ? and linked_in_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 390
        ig_amplify_count = (ig_posts.where("instagram_posts.updated_at >= ? and instagram_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).pluck(:completed_requests_count).reduce(:+) || 0) * 104

        reach_last_period += tw_amplify_count + fb_amplify_count + li_amplify_count + ig_amplify_count
    end

    # Do some more stuff with all the data we just grabbed and return it to the client
end
```

Comment: Are `tw_posts` and `fb_posts` and ... refer to different tables or do they reside in the same table?

Comment: They're all different tables. `TwitterPost`, `FacebookPost`, etc. They all `belong_to` `SocialMediaPost`, which `belongs_to` `Company` if that helps

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Maybe you can optimize it a bit with union selection, but either way you'll end up with querying multiple tables. Adding indexes to those timestamp columns can help speed up each query.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm thinking I might just set up a background task to calculate daily metrics so I can just query a single table. Seems like the only viable option for speeding this up.

Comment: You can use the aggregation method `sum(column)` like `(tw_posts.where("twitter_posts.updated_at >= ? and twitter_posts.updated_at < ?", date, date + 1).sum(:completed_requests_count)`.

Comment: That does seem to shave off about 100ms from the total response time, which is around 1400ms.

Comment: any time you are doing SQL queries in a loop you should try and use eager loading (includes or preload)